# SharePoint - Get Documents from a specific folder from another site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I'm building a site and would like that in this site I show some images which are in a specific folder in another site.

Any idea if that is possible and how it can be done. I know that with Highlighted Content I can show documents in different site but I do not have an idea how can I filter to a specific folder.

The images are found in this file path

[image]

Would you kindly help me out on this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you could use image web part to show image from another site:

[image]

Besides, for  Highlighted Content Web Part, you could add filter to show documents in a specific folder. Like the below:

[image]

Comment: In the folder I may have multiple images and not solely 1 image so do not think that it is possible to opt for the 1 option.


As for the second option I already tried however it does not show the image within the folder but shows the web page only

Comment: For the 2nd option, if you use folder path, it will not show the image. As a workaorund, you could use the document libary path.

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly but I could not find document library path in Managed Property name